# Any reason why one would call hide() before show()?

Tags: jquery

Why would one want to call hide() before show() ? I'd like to know this before i optimize this with method chaining..

```
function ShowSomething() {
  jQuery("something").hide();
  jQuery("something").show();
}
```

Comment: I'd call hide before fadeIn()

Comment: because only hidden elements can be shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling `hide()` the initial value of that element's `display` is stored for when `show()` is called, that initial value is put back in place. If no initial value is set, then `show()` will set `display:block`.

So, if an element was originally `display:inline`, but (let's say) `.css("display","none")` was called on that element, it would be hidden with no initial property saved. When we `show()` this element again it will be given `display:block` - not it's initial value of `inline` which is what it would be given if we'd used `hide()`.

To summarize: `hide()` will preserve the original `display` value ready for `show()` to use

Source: The jQuery [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) documentation

Comment: Where does this come from? Experience or documentation? I'm curious.

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference in the output if that was chained, other than jQuery will actually perform the DOM lookup twice on the non-chained version.

In terms of performance, non-chaining is actually 24% slower, as shown below:

[image: jsperf]

See my [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/chain-vs-no-chains)

Answer (score 0):

`.hide` will

> .hide() is fired immediately and will override the animation queue if
>   no duration or a duration of 0 is specified.

So, if the animation was already in the queue it would be removed, and then inserted with `.show()`. It can also be useful (visually) for certain animations where you go from non-existance to existance. You can chain them together, it will make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This usually comes up when you have a series of elements that need to be shown one at a time. First, you hide all elements with a certain class, then you show the one you want.